# Set consistent plot sizing in RShiny using Plotly Subplot in R

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, subplot

I am building an RShiny app to scrap and display USGS streamflow data.  The final plot panel has plots of differing sizes. How can I alter the code so that all of the plots in the subplot panel are the same size?  Here is the code I am using:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(dataRetrieval)
library(cowplot)
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("USGS Streamflow Data"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(dateInput("start_date", "Start Date:", value = Sys.Date() - 7), width = 2),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Carson Basin", plotlyOutput("C_plot_panel", width = "100%", height = "3000px"))
    )
  )
))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  #_______________ Carson Plot Panel
  output$C_plot_panel <- renderPlotly({
    # Split the site numbers entered by the user
    C_site_numbers <- list("10308200", "10309000", "10309010", "10310000",  "10311000","10311400", "10312000", "10312100", "10312150")
    C_site_names <- list("Markleeville (cfs)", "Gardnerville (cfs)", "Dresslerville (cfs)", "Woodfords (cfs)", "Carson @ Carson (cfs)", "Deer Run (cfs)", "Ft Churchill (cfs)", "Lahontan (acre-ft)", "Blw Lahontan (cfs)")
    
    # Create an empty list to store the individual plots
    C_plots <- list()
    
    # Loop through each site number and download/streamflow data
    for (C_site_number in C_site_numbers) {
      
      # Download streamflow data using dataRetrieval package
      start_date <- input$start_date
      end_date <- as.Date(Sys.Date())
      n <- which(C_site_numbers == C_site_number)
      plot_n <- unlist(C_site_names[n])
      para_code = if(plot_n == 'Lahontan (acre-ft)'){'00054'} else {'00060'}
      streamflow <- readNWISuv(siteNumbers = C_site_number, parameterCd = para_code, 
                               startDate = start_date, endDate = end_date)
      attr(streamflow$dateTime, 'tzone') <- "America/Los_Angeles"

      # Prepare data for plotting
      streamflow_df <- data.frame(
        Date = as.POSIXct(streamflow$dateTime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),
        Flow = if(plot_n == 'Lahontan (acre-ft)'){streamflow$X_00054_00000} else {streamflow$X_00060_00000}
      )
      colnames(streamflow_df[2]) <- plot_n

      # Create the plot using plotly
      plot <- plot_ly(data = streamflow_df, x = ~ Date, y = ~Flow, type = "scatter", mode = "lines")     %>%
        layout(yaxis = list(title = plot_n)) %>%
        layout(hovermode = "x unified", plot_bgcolor = 'rgb(212,213,214)', showlegend = FALSE)
      plot
      C_plots[[C_site_number]] <- plot
    }
    C_plot_panel <- subplot(C_plots, nrows = 8, titleY = TRUE, margin = 0.07) 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

First part of the code obtains and processes the USGS data using the dataRetrieval package.  Once the data is ready, the script then loops through each gage location to build the individual plot and groups all of the plots together into a subplot (plot panel).

Comment: You specified 8 rows for 9 plots. Once Plotly realized that at least one row would have two plots, while no specific domains were assigned, it automatically adjusted for 2 columns, thus returning 5 rows, that were stretched over what would have been 8 rows (meanwhile the plots were still sized to fit 8 rows). Instead of using a static number in `subplot(nrows = ...`, use something that's dynamic. For example, `subplot(nrows = ceiling(length(C_site_numbers)/2)...`. If you want 8 rows regardless of the number of plots, you need to assign domains to each plot.